# Is there a way to preserve HTML table data width on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table that has 17 columns. I am trying to make the Title, Description, and Status columns wider than other columns. I have tried giving each column header a unique width, and that has helped me make adjustments to column width. However, when I switch to a smaller screen, the column widths shrink. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening and allow the column widths to appear as they do on a larger screen?

[image: HTML Table with multiple attributes on small screen]

[image: HTML Table with multiple attributes on larger screen]

HTML Table Code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:2%">Order</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Title</th>
            <th style="width:26%">Description</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Cost Impact ($K)</th>
            <th style="width:2%">Schedule Impact (Months)</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Probability Occurrence (%)</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Factored Risk ($K)</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Cons</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Prob</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Risk Level</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Start Date</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Due Date</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Finish Date</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Status</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Gantt</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Funded</th>
            <th style="width:1%">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for task in tasks %}
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input name="task_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="task_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" value="{{ task.id }}" readonly hidden>
            </div> 
            <td>
                <input name="order_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="order_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.order}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input placeholder="Title" name="title_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="title_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" value="{{task.title}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="action_step_{{ forloop.counter }}"
                    id="action_step_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text"
                    value="{{ task.action_step }}" rows="1" cols="50">{{ task.action_step }}
                </textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="current_cost_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="current_cost_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.current_cost}}" placeholder="Current Cost ($K)" onkeyup="update_consequence({{ forloop.counter }});">    
            </td>
            <td>
                <input placeholder="Current Schedule (Months)" name="current_schedule_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="current_schedule_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" value="{{task.current_schedule}}" onkeyup="update_consequence({{ forloop.counter }});">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input placeholder="Probability of Occurrence (%)" name="quantified_probability_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="quantified_probability_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" value="{{task.quantified_probability}}" onkeyup="update_probability({{ forloop.counter }});">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="factored_risk_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="factored_risk_{{ forloop.counter }}"  value="{{task.factored_risk}}" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input readonly class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="consequence_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="consequence_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.consequence}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="probability_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="probability_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.probability}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="level_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="level_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.level}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="start_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="start_{{ forloop.counter }}"  type="date" value={{task.start_date|date:"Y-m-d"}} >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="due_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="due_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="date" value={{task.due_date|date:"Y-m-d"}}>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="finish_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="finish_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="date" value={{task.finish_date|date:"Y-m-d"}}>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="status_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="status_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{task.status}}">
                    <option {% if task.status == "Active" %}selected{% endif %} value="Active" >Active</option>
                    <option {% if task.status == "Complete" %}selected{% endif %} value="Complete" >Complete</option>
                    <option {% if task.status == "Planned" %}selected{% endif %} value="Planned" >Planned</option>
                    <option {% if task.status == "Proposed" %}selected{% endif %} value="Proposed" >Proposed</option>
                    <option {% if task.status == "OBE" %}selected{% endif %} value="OBE" >OBE</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                {% if task.gantt == True %}
                <input id="show_gantt_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="show_gantt_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="checkbox" checked>
                {%else%}
                <input id="show_gantt_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="show_gantt_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="checkbox">
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                {% if task.funded == True %}
                <input id="funded_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="funded_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="checkbox" checked>
                {%else%}
                <input id="funded_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="funded_{{ forloop.counter }}" type="checkbox">
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="button" id="delete" data-position="top center" onclick="delete_task('{{task.id}}','{{risk.id}}')" >X</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use PX insead of % in width sizes ,
for example : `<th style="width:20px">Order</th>`

Comment: table {table-layout:fixed;}

Comment: Czn you make your code into a working snippet which demonstrates the problem. I cannot reproduce the problem using just the code you have given. A short example of the generated HTML is needed.